# checboxes doesn't add checked attribute

Tags: twig, grav

Having some problems overriding the `Grav CMS` checboxes.
The problem is that `checked` attribute doesn't appear. For this purpose Grav uses the `{% if checked %}checked="checked"{% endif %}` in twig template. But it doesn't work. Just nothing is added after a click.

It doesn't work with my code.

The overridden `themes/child-theme/templates/forms/fields/checkboxes/checkboxes.html.twig`

```
{% extends "forms/field.html.twig" %}

{% set originalValue = value %}
{% set value = (value is null ? field.default : value) %}
{% if field.use == 'keys' and field.default %}
    {% set value = field.default|merge(value) %}
{% endif %}

{% block global_attributes %}
    {{ parent() }}
    data-grav-keys="{{ field.use == 'keys' ? 'true' : 'false' }}"
    data-grav-field-name="{{ (scope ~ field.name)|fieldName }}"
{% endblock %}

{% block input %}
    {% for key, text in field.options %}

        {% set id = field.id|default(field.name)|hyphenize ~ '-' ~ key %}
        {% set name = field.use == 'keys' ? key : id %}
        {% set val = field.use == 'keys' ? '1' : key %}
        {% set checked = (field.use == 'keys' ? value[key] : key in value) %}
        {% set help = (key in field.help_options|keys ? field.help_options[key] : false) %}

        <div class="checkboxes {{ form_field_wrapper_classes }} {{ field.wrapper_classes }}">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   id="{{ id|e }}"
                   value="{{ val|e }}"
                   name="{{ (scope ~ field.name)|fieldName ~ '[' ~ name ~ ']' }}"
                   class="{{ form_field_checkbox_classes }} {{ field.classes }}"
                   {% if checked %}checked="checked"{% endif %}
                   {% if field.disabled or isDisabledToggleable %}disabled="disabled"{% endif %}
            >
            <label style="display: inline" for="{{ id|e }}">
                {% if help %}
                    <span class="hint--bottom" data-hint="{{ help|t|e('html_attr') }}">{{ text|t|e }}</span>
                {% else %}
                    {{ text|t|e }}
                {% endif %}
            </label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The checkbox definitions in `md`

```
        -
            name: planner_project_type_checkbox
            type: checkboxes
            label: false
            options:
                Text Option: 'Text Value'
                Text Option: 'Text Value'
                Text Option: 'Text Value'
            outerclasses: 'fields-group-controls onyx-checkboxes'
            classes: onyx-checkboxes
```

DOM elements, no `checked="checked"` after click:
[image]

Nor with `quark theme`. Checkboxes definitions:

```
---
form:
    name: myform
    fields:
        -
            name: myField
            type: checkboxes
            options:
              option1: Option 1
              option2: Option 2         
---
```

DOM elements, no `checked="checked"` after click:
[image]

Comment: "Just nothing is added after a click." Why should Twig, which runs on the server, do anything when clicking something in the browser?

Comment: So, what's the logic in the `{% if checked %}checked="checked"{% endif %}` ? In other words, how can I add this attribute with native `Grav` built-in functionality, without using `JS`? I could add an attribute with `JS` script, but once such form is submitted, the checked elements don't appear in the email/data file. Also I need this in order to style elements, which have `checked` attribute, as for example: `.type-selection input[checked] + label {}`

Comment: 1) When Grav passes a form containing a checked checkbox (eg. as default value) to Twig, the Twig snippet you've shown will set attribute `checked="checked"`. 2) If you submit a form with a checked checkbox, but the form's `process` field contains `reset: true` (which clears the form's content), all following actions like email/data will be receiving an empty form. 3) No custom JS needed.

Comment: But why clicking on a checkbox the `checked="checked"` attribute doesn't appear in `html`? I've uploaded the screenshots to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"DOM elements, no checked="checked" after click"

That's how a checkbox works by design... See [MDN docs about the checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)

> `checked`
> A Boolean attribute indicating whether or not this checkbox is checked by default (when the page loads). It does not indicate whether this checkbox is currently checked: if the checkbox's state is changed, this content attribute does not reflect the change. (Only the HTMLInputElement's checked IDL attribute is updated.)

Note: "indicating whether or not this checkbox is checked **by default**"

Also, try the checkbox sample at the top of the page. There is no change in the DOM when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the clarifications! Can you explain about `{% if checked %}checked="checked"{% endif %}`m what it's doing? And, as I understand, there is no built-in solution to distinguish the state of a checkbox? In such way, I'm unable to style a checkbox depending on its state. As for example: `.type-selection input[checked] + label {}` won't work...

Comment: Twig: See first point in previous comment: It sets the `checked` attribute when the checkbox should be checked. CSS: " I'm unable to style a checkbox depending on its state", this is css basics. Please Google for ["css checkbox checked"](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+checkbox+checked&rlz=1C1ONGR_nlNL947NL947&oq=css+checkbox+checked&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.8428j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)